# Function template parameter type defined without actually specifying the parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm using templates for optimization - a function template has an integral parameter and a switch is used to resolve the condition once, while the actual function contains some heavy processing, which would otherwise need to resolve the condition several times. For example:

```
 template<int value> struct MIntValue 
 { static const int Value = value; typedef MIntValue Type; };

#define MTSWITCH3(index, value, command) \
switch(value) {\
    case 0: { MIntValue<0> T##index; typedef MIntValue<0> TT##index; command; }; break;\
    case 1: { MIntValue<1> T##index; typedef MIntValue<1> TT##index; command; }; break;\
    case 2: { MIntValue<2> T##index; typedef MIntValue<2> TT##index; command; }; break;\
    default: ASSERT(0);\
};

 template<class C1, class C2> void Fn(C1 c1, C2 c2, int param) 
 { for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) 
      if (C1::Value == 0 && C2::Value == 1) { do something; };
 };

MTSWITCH3(0, condition1,
     MTSWITCH3(1, condition2,
        Fn(T0, T1, param);
```

So, basically the actual switch is performed before the actual call by the compiler and one function is created per combination of the parameters. In release mode the condition inside the function is resolved by the compiler as these are just constants.

I have 2 remaining problems:

1. `C1` and `C2` are actually sent as parameters, I assume as 4B empty structures, but it's still waste of space. I'd like to call Fn like this:

   ```
   Fn<TT0::Type, TT1::Type>(param);
   ```

But I get lots of errors like missing ';' and such. Any idea why?

2. When the number of conditions is low, like 1-4, I can just write a macro for the switch. But if there are say 100 possibilities, I'm really not going to make a switch like that. Any ideas how to implement such a switch with templates? I'll probably do that by some kind of macro binary tree, but macros like this are extremely hard to manage.

Comment: What is `TT0::Type` and `TT1::Type`? And what do you mean by "4B empty structures"?

Comment: Maybe `Fn<typename TT0::Type, typename TT1::Type>(param);` ? I don't understand your code. Is Fn supposed to be called in Fn recursively, or are you missing brackets? Did you check to see if the compiler automatically optimizes based on values known at compile-time?

Comment: 4B is 4 bytes :). Kind of the minimum size parameter (depending on x86 vs x64 etc.). Neil: aaaah, sorry the final brackets are missing indeed. No recursion, I'll fix it. It's just a switch that ends up with 9 different calls to the function, with different template parameters each time.

Comment: If `TT0::Type` is a typedef of `TT0`, why don't you just put that directly as the parameter?

Comment: That's exactly what doesn't work... I get tons of errors such as missing ";". I was thinking I'm an idiot and I just mispelled something, but it doesn't look so... For the record, I'm using MSVC 2013 here.